# Finding parameter range of inequation with no solution

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, inequalities

Let the solution set of the following inequation

$$6 k - 2 x + k x^2 < 0, \quad k \neq 0$$
be an **empty set**. How can I find find the range of parameter $k$?

The following code gives an answer:

```
Reduce[{Discriminant[k x^2 - 2 x + 6 k, x] <= 0, k > 0}, k]
(* k >= 1/Sqrt[6] *)
```

However, the code below gives an error message `Resolve::elemc`. Can I fix the code somehow?

```
ForAll[x, x ∈ {}, k x^2 - 2 x + 6 k < 0 && k != 0]
Resolve[%, Reals]
Reduce[%, k, Reals]
(* During evaluation of In[540]:= Resolve::elemc: Unable to resolve 
   the domain or region membership condition x∈{}.
(* During evaluation of In[540]:= Resolve::elemc: Unable to resolve
   the domain or region membership condition `LocalVariable$1∈{}.
(* During evaluation of In[540]:= Resolve::elemc: Unable to resolve 
   the domain or region membership condition x∈{}.
(* ... *)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the opposite inequality `k x^2 - 2 x + 6 >= 0` and write down your preposition as

```
ForAll[x,k x^2 - 2 x + 6 >= 0]
```

Then

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, k x^2 - 2 x + 6 >= 0], Reals]
```

> `k >= 1/6`

As we see `k!=0`.